# Retrieving events from Firebase and displaying in react native agenda calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config'

const timeToString = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

export default function CalendarScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("")
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
  const userID = route.params ? route.params.nxtID : firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    const unsubscribe = usersRef.doc(userID).onSnapshot((documentSnapshot) => {
      setUser(documentSnapshot.data())
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

    const [items, setItems] = React.useState({});

    const loadItems = (day) => {

      setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
            const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            const strTime = timeToString(time);

            if (!items[strTime]) {
                items[strTime] = [];

                const numItems = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
                for (let j = 0; j < numItems; j++) {
                    items[strTime].push({
                        name: 'Item for ' + strTime + ' #' + j,
                        height: Math.max(10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)),
                        day: strTime
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        const newItems = {};
        Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
            newItems[key] = items[key];
        });
        setItems(newItems);
    }, 1000);
}


    const renderItem = (item) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Content>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Card.Content>
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Agenda
                items={items}
                loadItemsForMonth={loadItems}
                refreshControl={null}
                showClosingKnob={true}
                refreshing={false}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
            <StatusBar />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginTop: 17
    },
});
```

Trying to display events from firebase as events in a react native agenda calendar. Right now have it using an array to display auto generated events. Was wanting to see a way to retrieve event data from firebase and insert it into the array. Can see that it is actually linked to firebase by calling from console.
Any other solutions are greatly appreciated as well.